# can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

Tags: python-3.x, nonetype, responsetext

## Having issues with get api response Text and Print it in python3

```
response = session.get(url=url, headers=headers, json=payload, verify=cabundle,
                               auth=auth)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            print(response.status_code)
            print("Response is:")
            data = json.loads(response.text)
            print(data)
            if data['issues']!= []:
                issueId = data['issues'][0]['id']
                print("Issue ID :    " +issueId)
```

Output:

```
200
Response is:
Expecting value: line 3 column 1 (char 4)
can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

Can anyone help with this problem?

Comment: Please include the full Traceback when posting errors. The line number is very relevant here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if the `issueId` exists before concatenating:

```
issueId = data['issues'][0]['id']
if issueId:
    print("Issue ID : " + issueId)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! I am still getting the same error

Comment: @AkankshaJain please post the complete stack traceback error

Answer (score 2):

Use string params and it will insert `None` if it is none type.

`print(f"Issue Id: {issueId}")`

Comment: Thanks for responding! I am still getting the same error